# Angular JS: iframe con src cargado por código

Tags: angularjs, iframe

Tengo una aplicación Angular JS que genera correctamente un informe SSRS. Pero está hardcodeado. Quiero subir la URL desde la configuración.

Para hacer esto, reemplacé en la vista:

```
<div>
  <iframe ng-src="{{vm.report}}" height="600" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

donde vm.report es:

```
function BalancesController(.......) {
  var vm = this;

  function initialize() {
    vm.report = window.ReportLoadBaskets + "?rs:Embed=true";
  }
}
```

Pero me sale este error:

> Error: $sce:insecurl Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy. URL: http://pcxxx/Reports/report/Gener/Events?rs:Embed=true

Me podrán dar una mano para resolverlo?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usando el service [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) específicamente [`$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl)

```
vm.report = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(
  window.ReportLoadBaskets + "?rs:Embed=true"
);
```

> Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS constrains bindings to only render trusted values. Its goal is to assist in writing code in a way that (a) is secure by default, and (b) makes auditing for security vulnerabilities such as XSS, clickjacking, etc. a lot easier.

Nota:

A nivel aplicación podes definir los dominios o restricciones vía [`$sceDelegateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider)

ejemplo en la doc

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.trustedResourceUrlList([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
    'http://srv*.assets.example.com/**'
  ]);

  // The banned resource URL list overrides the trusted resource URL list so the open redirect
  // here is blocked.
  $sceDelegateProvider.bannedResourceUrlList([
    'http://myapp.example.com/clickThru**'
  ]);
});
```

Comment: Ahí anduvo!! Lo había probado de esa manera y no me andaba pero faltaba agregar el parámetro '$sce' en el $inject. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: si, no incluí el inject y la config del app pq depende de cómo le tengas armado. a nivel app podes definir los dominios o constraints válidos, esa config luego se usa en cada controller donde injectas el asunto.